# Nginx not forwarding custom domain requests to the correct port

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, node.js

I have a website that allows users to create portfolios for their websites, they simply change their A records on their domain and put my server IP address into their records and it will map to their website (user1.example.com). My problem is, I purchased a domain to test this (example.com) and it routes them to the homepage of my actual website where you can use this service.

The only way a user can access their website is via: `http://example.com:3000` - 3000 being the port that my Node.js app runs on. My Nginx config is below, can anybody throw me a bone?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/example.com.key;

    server_name example.com *.example.com "";
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    root /opt/33i/;

    # Perfect forward secrecy
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/dhparams.pem;
    ssl_ciphers ;

    # HSTS
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? This has been driving me mad!

Comment: If it reaches your server, and your application, this sounds like an application level issue rather than routing / network / Nginx.

Comment: Hi @Tim, it only reaches the application using http://example:3000 - I'm pointing example.com to the server IP address, which runs on port 80 then proxies it across to 3000, but it goes to the main server web page, not the domain that I was requesting, I feel like the domain I was requesting is getting lost somewhere in the proxy pass.

Comment: Can you try `$host` instead of `$http_host`? Are you sure the node.js configuration is correct? Also your ssl_ciphers is empty.

Comment: Your application needs to recognize *their* domain. Your `user1.example.com` name no longer plays any part in this.

Comment: @RichardSmith if it's dynamic, I can't create a vhost for it - so I don't know exactly what the user set their domain as, all we have is what they told us in our database. So if the user sets example.com in their settings and point that domain CNAME to us, we expect to match that, but the host is not coming through so I cannot match it on my end.

Comment: @Grumpy My Node config has been stripped down fully, so I'm just looking at all incoming connections, everything comes through fine apart from custom domain names - they come through as my primary domain, not the user's domain.

Comment: Nginx does not see the CNAME value. Your clients need to set their domain in your control panel.

Comment: `karlhadwen.com` is an A record at the moment and pointing to the same IP address as `user.33i.co`. You should make your hello world test something useful like printing the value of the HTTP Host header.

Comment: I cannot see how this has anything to do with your `nginx` configuration. The Host header is there - how you are deducing "10" is locked inside your application.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be on the `server_name` line.

As it is currently implemented, it matches the following kinds of requests:

- `Host:` header being `example.com`
- `Host:` header ending with `.example.com`
- `Host:` header missing

This means that this configuration doesn't match arbitrary domains, which looks like what you want to happen.

Now, most likely you have another `server` block in your configuration with:

listen 443 ssl default_server;

The virtual host containing this directive is the catch-all virtual host for requests that aren't otherwise matched.

So, to fix your issue, you need to remove the `default_server` directive from the `server` block where it is now, and add `default_server` to this blocks' `listen` directives.

Comment: Hi Tero, thank you for your response, you're my only hope at this point! I only have one server block, so I'm not 100% sure about your last point, if it's not too much hassle would you be able to put a server block together or modify my current block? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Most nginx installations do have a default server block somewhere in their configuration files. You can find it out by adding `default_server` into your `listen` directive and running `nginx -t`. If nginx doesn't complain, then it doesn't have a default server block. However, then your original setup should not behave like this.

Comment: I've run that particular command and checked my files and made sure that I've no default server block, this is the only Nginx configuration that I have.

Comment: So did you add the `default_server` directive yet?